# SELECT gives different results with/without FOR UPDATE in same transaction

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, select

I'm sorry but I havent't found a better wording for the title.

Given the table `a`:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id INT NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
    ref VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    val INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO a(ref, val) VALUES ('ten', 10);
```

And two transactions `Tx1` and `Tx2` with default isolation level, whose queries are issued in the following order, is the result shown in step `[*]` of transaction `Tx2`expected?

```
Tx1: START TRANSACTION;

            Tx2: START TRANSACTION;

            [^] Tx2: SELECT * FROM a WHERE id='1';
            (without FOR UPDATE)
            ===>
                "id"    "ref"   "val"
                "1"     "ten"   "10"

Tx1: SELECT * FROM a WHERE id='1' FOR UPDATE;
===>
    "id"    "ref"   "val"
    "1"     "ten"   "10"

            Tx2: SELECT * FROM a WHERE id='1' FOR UPDATE;
            (waits)

Tx1: UPDATE a SET v=20 WHERE id;

Tx1: COMMIT;

            Tx2: (locked on 'SELECT * FROM a WHERE id='1' FOR UPDATE')
            (unlocks)
            ===>
                "id"    "ref"   "val"
                "1"     "ten"   "20"

            [*] Tx2: SELECT * FROM a WHERE id='1';
            (without FOR UPDATE)
            ===>
                "id"    "ref"   "val"
                "1"     "ten"   "10"
```

`[*]`: Shouldn't this give the updated row value `20` for column `val`?

UPDATE: If I remove the query `[^]`, then `[*]` yields the value `20`.

This is on `5.6.39`; queries were issued using third party client - HeidiSQL - though I guess that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Do you mean that you run `[*]` immediately after the `select ... for update` returned? And then you get a different value than the previously finished select?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, I reported the exact sequence of queries issued in each transaction.

Comment: That indeed sounds strange. What happens when you use `read committed` instead of the default `repeatable read`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, with that isolation level I get the expected value of `20` - in the meantime I added a small _update_.

Answer (score 1):

A guess:

"Repeatable Read" means that the *identical* `SELECT` will produce identical results throughout the transaction.  But, apparently, the `FOR UPDATE` clause is enough to make the two selects not 'identical'.

Under the covers...  There is a clock (sequence number) ticking away.  Whenever a row is modified, it is copied over.  Now there are two copies of that row, one with the old clock, one with the new.  (See "History list".)  Your first `SELECT` is associated with the older clock value; the second `SELECT`, not being identical to the first, has a newer clock value, hence linked to a different copy of the row.

After the transaction if finished (`COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`), the extra copy of the row is tossed.  (I think this is a background task for `COMMIT`, but a "do it now" task for `ROLLBACK`.)  Meanwhile, other connections pick the appropriate row from the history list for each row based on their isolation_mode.  Roughly speaking, `READ_COMMITTED` goes to the old end of the list; `READ_UNCOMMITTED` ("dirty read") goes to the new end.

Things are optimized on the "optimistic" assumption that `COMMITs` are more likely than `ROLLBACKs`.  Hence, the comments in the previous paragraph, and the slowness of `ROLLBACK`.